# How to extract properties from a xml file matching pattern on keys

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

I have a file with something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property><name>key1.somestuff.someotherstuff</name><value>value1</value></property><property><name>key2.somestuff.someotherstuff</name><value>value2</value></property></configuration>
```

So the file i get as input is not properly formatted, and i need to copy some of these properties matching a pattern to another xml file. 
How can i extract segments for this file in shell (using grep or sed or any such tool) for a given pattern in key.
For example if the code was formatted properly i could have used:

```
grep --no-group-separator -a2 "key1"
```

How can i extract segment for a certain key like for key1:

```
<property>
  <name>key1.somestuff.someotherstuff</name>
  <value>value1</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Your xml input isn‘t valid xml.

Comment: @Cyrus yeah, sorry for that, it is a hand written example, corrected that.

Comment: Okay. Your example contains twice `key1.somestuff.someotherstuff`. Is this intended?

Comment: @Cyrus that was just to give format, changed the names  to different to have different values. No, that was not intended

Comment: @user1560339: Can you use `xmllint`? Can you download and install it?

Comment: @Inian Ok, will try xmllint, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` with `xml` is generally not a good idea. Suggest using XML aware tools like [`xmllint`](http://www.xmlsoft.org) for this case.  Instructions to download and install are available in the link.

Using `xmllint` a simple `xpath` parser logic like below

```
xmllint --xpath '/configuration/property[contains(name,"key1.somestuff.someotherstuff")]' input-xml
```

should solve your case. The logic is pretty straight forward. Start at root node, `configuration` to `property` and get the node `name` value, only if it contains the string you needed.

Since your file in the description if formatted as a flat-line, the above command produces a flat output like:

```
xmllint --xpath '/configuration/property[contains(name,"key1.somestuff.someotherstuff")]' input-xml
<property><name>key1.somestuff.someotherstuff</name><value>value1</value></property>
```

Assuming I modify your input file to a proper XML structure as:

```
$ cat modified-xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>key1.somestuff.someotherstuff</name>
        <value>value1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>key2.somestuff.someotherstuff</name>
        <value>value2</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

outputs something like below:-

```
<property>
        <name>key1.somestuff.someotherstuff</name>
        <value>value1</value>
    </property>
```